# Need help understanding logic of function

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

```
monthly->maxTemperature = yearData[i].high;
monthly->minTemperature = yearData[i].low;
```

I just can't seem to understand the logic of what the iterations will look like or how to access the proper elements in the array of data to get the proper data for each month.... without corrupting data. Thanks!

Comment: any pointers to any resources elsewhere would be wonderful as well. Thank you!

Comment: Post the `Data` structure.

Comment: struct Data{
       int day;
       int month;
       int year;
       float high;
       float low;
       float precip;
       };

Comment: then pass back to one that will hold the proper values of each month

Comment: I am bit confuse between void stats and getStats. The latter is used to get statics but what is aim of former function

Comment: It's really not clear what you are asking. The closest to a question you have is "I just can't seem to understand the logic of what the iterations will look like". But that is a bit vague. What precisely is wrong with your current code (which you have not really shown enough of)? The two obvious problems in your code are that you don't check the input `mth` before updating the max/min/avg and `average+= yearData[i];` is clearly wrong as the types are incompatible on either side of that assignment.

Comment: I guess a more precise question would be how does the iteration logic work behind this for calculating the correct values for a proper months stats.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track:

```
void stats(int mth, const struct Data yearData[], int size, struct Monthly* monthStats)
{
    // These are used to calc averages
    int highSum = 0;
    int lowSum = 0;
    int days = 0;

    // Initialize data
    monthly->maxTemperature = INT_MIN;
    monthly->minTemperature = INT_MAX;
    monthly->totalPrecip = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        // Only use data from given month
        if (yearData[i].month == mth) {
            days += 1;
            if (yearData[i].high > monthly->maxTemperature) monthly->maxTemperature = yearData[i].high;
            if (yearData[i].low < monthly->minTemperature) monthly->minTemperature = yearData[i].low;
            highSum += yearData[i].high;
            lowSum + yearData[i].low;
            monthly->totalPrecip += yearData[i].precip;
        }
     }

     if (0 != days) {
         monthly->avgHigh = highSum / days;
         monthly->avgLow = lowSum / days;
     }
}
```

Comment: ahhhh OK, so once you figure out if the months are matching... you perform the calculations. Thank you sir

Answer (score 0):

Before working on the assignment it's a good idea to examine the API that you need to implement for clues. First thing to notice is that the reason the `struct Monthly` is passed to your function by pointer is so that you could set the result into it. This is different from the reason for passing `struct Data` as a pointer<sup>*</sup>, which is to pass an array using the only mechanism for passing arrays available in C. `const` qualifier is a strong indication that you must not be trying to modify anything off of the `yearData`, only the `monthStats`.

This tells you what to do with the min, max, average, and total that you are going to find in your function: these need to be assigned to fields of `monthStats`, like this:

```
monthStats->maxTemperature = maxTemperature;
monthStats->minTemperature = minTemperature;
...
```

where `maxTemperature`, `minTemperature`, and so on are *local variables* that you declare before entering the `for` loop.

As far as the `for` loop goes, your problem is that you ignore the `mth` variable completely. You need to use its value to decide if an element of `yearData` should be considered for your computations or not. The simplest way is to add an `if` to your `for` loop:

```
int maxTemperature = INT_MIN; // you need to include <limits.h>
int minTemperature = INT_MAX; // to get definitions of INT_MIN and INT_MAX
for(int i = 0; i<size; ++i) {
    if (yearData[i].month < mth) continue;
    if (yearData[i].month > mth) break;
    ... // Do your computations here
}
```

<sup>*</sup> Even though it looks like an array, it is still passed as a pointer

Comment: @bp06km The only thing that may be slightly tricky is the `continue`/`break` logic. It works like that because `yearData` is sorted by month. In other words, if we see that `month` is too low, we skip to the next iteration; once `month` get too high, we know we can exit the loop.